# Bootpag populate parameter with div attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following plugin: http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('[data-pagination]').bootpag({
    total: $(this).data('total'),
    maxVisible: 5,
    firstLastUse: true,
    leaps: true,
    next: '&rsaquo;',
    prev: '&lsaquo;',
    first: '&laquo;',
    last: '&raquo;'
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-pagination="customer" data-total="5"></div>
```

The problem is that it is not working. The `total` parameter is not being populated, so the pagination is not showing anything.

How would I pass the `data-total` attribute to the bootpag `total` parameter properly?

Comment: Try $(this).attr("data-total").

Comment: It works when I use `$('[data-pagination]').data('total')`, however, this is not an ideal solution because there could be more than one pagination element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` doesn't seem to point to the object when used this way. Since total can be different for each occurrence of the element, you have to invoke bootpag on each of them seperately.

Try this:

```
$('[data-pagination]').each(function() {
    $(this).bootpag({
      total: $(this).data('total'),
      maxVisible: 5,
      firstLastUse: true,
      leaps: true,
      next: '&rsaquo;',
      prev: '&lsaquo;',
      first: '&laquo;',
      last: '&raquo;'
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.